# pygame crash right after taking an action

Tags: python, pygame

Im new at Python, so the problem at my code is probably a silly one.
Right after the image of the player is moving, the window of the pygame is crashing without an error message at the IDLE.

im using Python 2.7.
Here's the code:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
dis=pygame.display.set_mode((1084,638),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('ledders and snakes')

FPS=30
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
White=(255,255,255)
img=pygame.image.load('smal.gif')
bg = pygame.image.load("under.gif")

cax=150
cay=150
di='right'
flag=True

while flag:
    dis.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if di=='right':
        cax+=10
        cay-=10
        if cax==280:
            di='down'
    elif di=='down':
        cay+=10
        cax+=10
        if cax==410:
            flag=False


    dis.blit(img,(cax,cay))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Does it work if run from the command line?  There are sometimes issues with Tk based applications running on IDLE (which is also Tk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look through your program and the issue is that you set `flag = False` when `if cax == 410`. That is why your program quits, because the condition becomes True after just a couple of seconds. But there are many things you should consider, so I made some changes (not in the program but in names):

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1084, 638  # Have a reference to WIDTH and HEIGHT.
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE, 0, 32)  # 'screen' is the convention and describes the variable better than 'dis'.
pygame.display.set_caption('ledders and snakes')

FPS = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Use lowercase for variables.
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)  # Use CAPS for constants.
img = pygame.Surface((32, 32))  # Used these two lines because I don't have your image.
img.fill((0, 0, 255))
bg = pygame.Surface((32, 32))    # Used these two lines because I don't have your image.
bg.fill((255, 0, 0))

cax = 150  # Since I don't know your program I can't tell if these are describable variables or not. 
cay = 150
direction = 'right'  # 'di' isn't describable enough.
running = True  # 'flag' seems like an indescribable variable.

while running:
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if direction == 'right':
        cax += 10
        cay -= 10
        if cax == 280:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        cay += 10
        cax += 10
        if cax == 410:
            running = False

    screen.blit(img, (cax, cay))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Also, put spaces between operators as ´==´ or after commas such as ´(0, 0)´instead of (0,0). And use variable names with lowercase, where words are separated with underscore. Try to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), as long as it doesn't make sense to break it.

Comment: thanks for the remarks!! and I know that the program get out from the loop right after a couple of seconds, it does what it should, but right after it just crash..

Comment: @roni280 The program doesn't crash but quits because it runs out of code. It breaks out of the while loop and ends. If it crash it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

I just skimmed over your program, if I'm not wrong (hopefully I'm not) you keep adding 10 to cax, the result is that your player reaches the position which will set flag to false after just 26 iterations in your while loop.
This will happen quite fast.

Comment: but why is that crash right after it quit from the loop?

Comment: It is your while loop, that is blitting the screen and updating.

Comment: No while loop, no blitting and updating, so don't expect your programm to still be opened up.